# Leibniz integral rule for improper integral with variable limit

Tags: derivatives, improper-integrals

Given an integral of the form $F(x)=\int_{t_0}^x f(x,t)dt$, where the function $f(x,t)$ is infinite at $t=x$, what are the minimal assumptions on $f(x,t)$ for the Leibniz integral rule to apply? I need to derive $F'(x)$.

Comment: Examine it for $\int_{t_0}^{x-h}$ for a fixed $h$, then take the limit as $h \to 0$. If the $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ term is not infinite, or is infinite, but fails to cancel out the infinitude of $f$, $F'(x)$ cannot exist.